# Django rest framework - Create or update values from json

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am very much new to Django and Django Rest Framework. I have an API whose json format is as below (Simplified version for sake of simplicity)

```
{
    "title" : "Lorem ipsum is a dummy title",
    "content" : "Lorem ipsum is a demo content"
    "tags" : ["Movies", "Food"]
}
```

Here is how my **model** looks like:

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    class Meta:
         verbose_name_plural = "Tags"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is how my serializer (Tags, Posts) looks like:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'

    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Tag.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.save()
        return instance

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'tags')

    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=1000)
    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Tag.objects.all())

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
        # [do i need to look for tags, create if not exists and retrieve the ids]

        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for tg in tags:
            post.tags.add(tg)
        return post

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.content = validated_data.get('content', instance.content)

        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')

        # [do i need to check for tags, create if not exists and retrieve the ids]
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

So I wish to save the post details with tags such that it create the tags if not exists. As i am new to django and rest framework i am not sure if there is some out of the box functionality available to achieve this. Or do I need to write some code in my **PostSerializer** that manually creates new tags and return the ids, then save them with post model?

Let me know if you want further information

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use Django's [**`get_or_create()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method as,

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
    post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for tag in tags:
        tag_obj, create = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
        post.tags.add(tag_obj)
    return post
```

The **`get_or_create()`** method will return  a tuple of **`(object, created)`**, where object is the retrieved or created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.